# Create Fragments within Fragment Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android

My `MainActivity` has `BottomNavigationBar` with 4 tabs that create new fragments:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    int mainFragmentLayout;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        mainFragmentLayout = Resource.Id.fragmentLayout;
        var bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);

        //Item in Navigation Bar clicked
        bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.action_home:
                    //Create Fragment View when Item is Clicked
                    Fragment homeFragment = new HomeLayoutFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction homeFragmentTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    homeFragmentTx.Replace(mainFragmentLayout, homeFragment);
                    homeFragmentTx.Commit();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.action_map:
                    //Create Fragment View when Item is Clicked
                    /*
                    Fragment mapFragment = new MapLayoutFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction mapFragmentTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    mapFragmentTx.Replace(mainFragmentLayout, mapFragment);
                    mapFragmentTx.Commit();
                    */
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.action_camera:
                    //Create Fragment View when Item is Clicked
                    Fragment cameraFragment = new CameraLayoutFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction cameraFragmentTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    cameraFragmentTx.Replace(mainFragmentLayout, cameraFragment);
                    cameraFragmentTx.Commit();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.action_profile:
                    //Create Fragment View when Item is Clicked
                    Fragment profileFragment = new ProfileLayoutFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction profileFragmentTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    profileFragmentTx.Replace(mainFragmentLayout, profileFragment);
                    profileFragmentTx.Commit();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
```

From there, when I go to the `homeFragment`, I create `ImageButtons` inside a `GridView`.

```
class HomeLayoutFragment : Fragment
{
    private const string TAG = "InfiniteScroll";
    private GridView _gridView;
    private MySimpleItemLoader _mySimpleItemLoader;
    private MyGridViewAdapter _gridviewAdapter;
    private readonly object _scrollLockObject = new object();
    private const int ItemsPerPage = 24;

    private const int LoadNextItemsThreshold = 6;
    Context context;
    public override void OnAttach(Context context)
    {
        base.OnAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomeGridView, container, false);

        _mySimpleItemLoader = new MySimpleItemLoader();
        _mySimpleItemLoader.LoadMoreItems(ItemsPerPage);

        _gridView = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);

        if (IsAdded)
        {
            _gridviewAdapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(context, _mySimpleItemLoader);
            _gridView.Adapter = _gridviewAdapter;
            _gridView.Scroll += KeepScrollingInfinitely;
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void KeepScrollingInfinitely(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollEventArgs args)
    {
        lock (_scrollLockObject)
        {
            var mustLoadMore = args.FirstVisibleItem + args.VisibleItemCount >= args.TotalItemCount - LoadNextItemsThreshold;
            if (mustLoadMore && _mySimpleItemLoader.CanLoadMoreItems && !_mySimpleItemLoader.IsBusy)
            {
                _mySimpleItemLoader.IsBusy = true;
                Log.Info(TAG, "Requested to load more items");
                _mySimpleItemLoader.LoadMoreItems(ItemsPerPage);
                _gridviewAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                _gridView.InvalidateViews();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My desired behavior is that the `ImageButtons` inside `GridView` when clicked, create a new `Fragment` that Adds it to my `MainActivity` `FragmentManger`.
What would be the best way to create these dynamic `Fragments` from within a `Fragment`?

Should I be using `FragmentActivity` in the `homeFragment` class? Should I use the `ViewPager` with `Fragments`? I've been looking all day and I'm not sure the best method to be using anymore.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a adaptive `Fragment` with its layout, cause it's easier to create a flexible layout rather than to create a new fragment each time.

And since you're using `BottomNavigationView`, I think the first problem of your requirement is to dynamically add item to this menu, you can do this in the item click event for example like this:

```
var bar = this.Activity.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
var menu = bar.Menu;
string itemstring = "XXXXX";
menu.Add(0, 1001, Menu.None, itemstring);
```

Then it will add a new item into the menu. But since it is dynamic, when you app is restarted, this item will be lost, you may save it and every time when you load your `MainActivity`, check your saved data and add menu items. If you have problem about saving data and retrieve data, there are many methods and you may google for them.

Then you may change the code in `NavigationItemSelected` like this:

```
...
    default:
        AdaptiveFragment fragment = new AdaptiveFragment();
        Bundle bd = new Bundle();
        var message = e.MenuItem.TitleFormatted.ToString();
        bd.PutString("message", message);
        fragment.Arguments = bd;
        transaction1.Replace(Resource.Id.framelayout, fragment).AddToBackStack(null).Commit();
        break;
...
```

The `AdaptiveFragment` is like this:

```
public class AdaptiveFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.adaptivelayout, container, false);
        string message = this.Arguments.GetString("message");
        //create dynamically view for this fragment based on the message.
        return view;
    }
}
```

The layout `adaptivelayout` is en empty layout with root `RelativeLayout` by my side. The key point here is to create menu item according to the `GridView`'s item using string parameter as menu title. Then based on the title to navigate to `AdaptiveFragment` and pass the title as parameter to this fragment, and finally according to this string parameter create relative layout and code logic in `Fragment`. The `AdaptiveFragment` here is more like a empty container.